# Как сбросить ARP кеш через WinAPI?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

Есть команда для сброса кеша: netsh interface ip delete arpcache

Как сделать тоже самое через WinAPI?

Comment: А чем команда не устраивает? Самое простое.

Comment: @iluxa1810, просто - да, но неправильно. Надо всегда стараться делать хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

Например, через [FlushIpNetTable function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365905(v=vs.85).aspx).